# How to append a line of JavaScript (rather than an exteral .js file)?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to append a script tag which executes one line of JavaScript to the head of a document, rather than appending a script tag which is empty and uses the src attribute.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var scriptContents = 'alert("hi")';
var theScript = document.createElement('script');
theScript.type = 'text/javascript';
theScript.appendChild(scriptContents);
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(theScript);
</script>
```

It's the appendChild(scriptContents) part that I'm having trouble with.  How do I change this to get the alert to appear in the browser?

Comment: Hmm, jsut going by the giving example - are you after different behaviour than simpling using `eval( theScript )`?

Comment: Yeah, I know it's kinda funny.  I need to use JavaScript to insert and HTML element, and this HTML element is a script tag with some JavaScript in it.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood what Jake was saying. If you just want to run a script, you can use the eval function.

Comment: For inscrutable reasons, the client wants the script element inserted into the DOM, rather than running the script.

Comment: But... but.. inserting it into the DOM WILL run the script.. I'm highly confused. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to append it as a text node. Try this:

```
theScript.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scriptContents));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do

```
theScript.appendChild(scriptContents);
```

as `appendChild()` only appends nodes, it can't append text. You need to make a text node with:

```
var scriptContents=document.createTextNode('alert("hi");')
```

However, as Jake mentioned above, you probably just want to do:

```
eval('alert("hi")');
```

Comment: var scriptContents=document.createTextNode('alert("hi");')


worked great.
From the earliest times I've been taught eval() = bad.
Why would I use it instead please?

Comment: When taught "eval() = bad" you need to ask yourself "why?". Executing arbitrary user input is bad and this can happen extremely easily with eval(); it is just as easy to append user input to a `<script>` tag and have it execute...

Comment: I was always lead to believe eval() had a large overhead.
Although, yes, executing arbitrary user input is bad too.

Comment: overhead is also a factor, though (while I've not tested this - I could be very wrong) I can't imagine pasting a string into a script element at runtime being massively efficient.