# Appending inline javascript to a script tag

Tags: javascript, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to append a line of JavaScript (rather than an exteral .js file)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267485/how-to-append-a-line-of-javascript-rather-than-an-exteral-js-file)

I am trying to create script tag dynamically. I want to append the inline javascript to a script tag.

My code

```
  var script = document.createElement("script")  
  script.type = "text/javascript";   
  var scriptContents = 'var isActive; window.onfocus = function () { isActive = true; }; window.onblur = function () { isActive = false; };';
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(scriptContents);   
  script.appendChild(textNode);
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

The reason i want to do this is to detect whether browser tab is active or not

My code fails with error

> SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access.

on line

```
script.appendChild(textNode);
```

Thanks for help

Comment: So you're wanting to put javascript content inside of the script tags you created dynamically?

Comment: There is pretty much no reason to do this.  If the code is already known, then it can just be a function in your other code that you call when desired.  If you truly need to dynamically add code, then you can use `eval()` to add code from text.